# PHP Regex help, getting part of a link

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to write a regex in php that in a line like

```
 <a href="mypage.php?(some junk)&p=12345&(other junk)" other link stuff>Text</a>
```

and it will only return me "p=12345", or even "12345". Note that the (some junk)& and the &(otherjunk) may or may not be present.
Can I do this with one expression, or will I need more than one? I can't seem to work out how to do it in one, which is what I would like if at all possible. I'm also open to other methods of doing this, if you have a suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$url = 'mypage.php?(some junk)&p=12345&(other junk)';
$parsed_url = parse_url($url);
parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_str);
echo $parsed_str['p'];
```

Comment: The problem I'm having with this is that with some links (some junk)& may not be there, resulting in a link like:    mypage.php?p=12345&(other junk), where this doesn't seem to work. Any way to remedy this?

Comment: I was actually unable to get this to work until I changed $parsed_str = parse_str($parsed_url['query']); to parse_str($parsed_url['query'], $parsed_str);, but thanks for your reply, it was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @user48518, Sorry for that. Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better tactic over using a regular expressoin in this case is to use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

You can use that to get the query (what comes after the ? in your URL) and split on the '&' character and then the '=' to put things into a nice dictionary.